# How to perform podman login inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, podman

I am trying to use podman inside a docker container, with no intention to run containers. podman will be used only for login, pull and push.

I am using python:3.7-bullseye docker image, and install the following packages:

```
RUN apt-get -y install runc
RUN apt-get -y install podman
```

Post install, podman is working and accessible:

```
root@992b0476dcf2:~# podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE   COMMAND  CREATED  STATUS  PORTS   NAMES
root@992b0476dcf2:~# podman version
Version:      3.0.1
API Version:  3.0.0
Go Version:   go1.15.9
Built:        Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

When I try to perform a podman login, I get errored as below:

```
root@992b0476dcf2:~# podman login my-special-registry:8080
Username: my-special-user
Password:
Error: error authenticating creds for "my-special-registry:8080": error creating new docker client: readdirent: not a directory
```

Could someone please help in explaining what is the path being referenced here which is not a directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message was a bit misleading. After spending a few hours on this, figured out the issue was because of a badly formatted ca-certificate which I placed on the /etc/containers path.

It may help to add --log-level=debug to pinpoint issues related to podman.

Answer (score 0):

A podman login to a private registry as the root user records the authentication under `/run/containers/0/auth.json` by default.  It will write to `${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/containers/auth.json` if the variable is set. Verify that the `/run/containers` path exists, is a directory and you have permission to write to it from within the container.  Then do the same for `${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/containers` if it exists.

My guess is a bind mount of a file on somewhere in one of the paths above is putting a file where podman is expecting a directory to be.  This is preventing the application from writing out the auth.json file under that path.

You can also explicitly override the auth file path using `export REGISTRY_AUTH_FILE=<path>`.  Test a login after setting this to a known writable value.

```
touch /tmp/auth.json
export REGISTRY_AUTH_FILE=/tmp/auth.json
podman login my-special-registry:8080
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights! The error message was a bit misleading. After spending few hours on this, figured out the issue was because of a badly formatted ca-certificate which I placed on the /etc/containers path.